# Обновление данных из power bi desktop происходит без ошибок, а в веб-версии - всегда с ошибкой

Tags: powerbi

Есть запрос "Данные". От него создана ссылка в виде таблицы "Соисполнители-задачи".

При обновлении данных в десктоп-версии, никогда подобной ошибки не возникало.
При обновлении данных в веб-версии из вкладки "Наборы данных" такая ошибка постоянна, причем, таблицы с одним и тем же типом ошибки - рандомные, видимо, до кого дойдет в первую очередь обработка.

Очень много было потрачено времени на поиск решения в [обществе Powerbi](https://community.powerbi.com/) и вообще в интернете.

[image: редактор]

[image: Описание ошибки]

[image: Редактор запроса таблицы Соисполнители-задачи]

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка, вроде как, на второй строке. При обращении к имени поля "tasks":
tasks = Источник[tasks]

Вы уверены, что такое поле есть? Может все-таки возможна ситуация, когда по какой-то причине поле "tasks" отсутствует в коллекции полей?
Я бы провел тест. Создайте вот такой запрос. Пусть он загрузит в модель таблицу, содержащую имена полей проблемной записи. Постройте по этой таблице визуализацию - таблицу.

```
let
    Source = Источник,
    fieldList = Record.FieldNames(Source),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(fieldList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

Опубликуйте отчет. Обновите данные на Power BI service. Зайдите в отчет и посмотрите какие  имена полей перечислены в сделанной вами визуализации. Есть ли там поле tasks?
Ну это первый шаг. Дальше - по обстоятельствам.
На всякий случай, хотя вряд ли в этом дело, переименуйте имя шага:
tasks = Source[tasks]
например на
tasksData = Source[tasks]